# Bootstrap grid to show user selected posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to develop my first wordpress theme which should show a bootstrap grid with 4 images. Each of these images should be linked to a specific post page, that the user can select in the wp-admin section.

It should also show some text that the user enters and a link.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div id ="show" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1" ><img src="featured image of post user selected" alt="description of post user selected"/></div>
        <div id ="show" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1" ><img src="featured image of post user selected" alt="description of post user selected"/></div>
        <div id ="show" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1" ><img src="featured image of post user selected" alt="description of post user selected"/></div>
        <div id ="show" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1" ><img src="featured image of post user selected" alt="description of post user selected"/></div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><p>some text the user specifys</p></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3"><a href="a link the user specifys">my link</a></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I've investigated creating a loop but I do not want to simply loop through my posts and show the first 4. The user must be able to select which posts to display in each image. Is this possible?

Comment: you can do it, but in wordPress you basically work with php template and you are just showing HTML... I recommend you to read the documentation:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: I know you work with PHP but all I've been able to find so far is to display all post items in a grid. I've shown the HTML as I thought it was the easiest way to describe what I'm trying to do!

Comment: so you insert this html in the php template and you adjust the number of posts with the wp_query. And Example http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135881/style-first-3-posts-differently-with-wp-query
(In the while loop you need to put these html elements)

Comment: The thing is.. i don't want to get the top x posts... i want the user to be able to pick specific posts to display in the grid. Is this possible?

Comment: you can find the posts by tag or category... just create a tag or category "Featured" and with wp_query you can filter them

Comment: so what I want to do isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution inserting HTML in the WP_Query

I made something fast to you, if you use this code you can make what you want inserting the HTML in the right places:

```
<?php

$lifestyle_cat = array(
    'category_name' => 'home',
    'showposts' => 4,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$lifestyle_query = new WP_Query( $lifestyle_cat );
if ( $lifestyle_query->have_posts()) {
    $i = 0; 
    while ( $lifestyle_query->have_posts()) {
       $i++;
       $lifestyle_query->the_post(); ?>  
       <div id ="show" class="col-xs-3 col-sm-1 col-md-1" > 
       //title
       <?php  the_title();
        if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
            // only print out the thumbnail if it actually has one
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
        }
    ?></div><?php
    } 
} 
?>
```

[thumbnail reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

[wp_query reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. But, won't this just show top 4 posts from category 'home' rather than allowing the user to select which post is shown on each one?

Comment: You can use customfields and there you can set the order of the posts
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters
But also there is ACP plugin where you cam embed in your theme and make new fields to set order:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: Is that question solved? will you close this question? will mark as solved ?